# Apache and Weblogic module rewrites to cluster

Tags: apache, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have a setup where we have two servers.  The WS server is used for serving all static content (images,css etc) and runs apache.  This is the hitting point for all requests.

The AS server together is a Weblogic cluster made up of two weblogic servers.

All .jsp requests go to AS server.

I have to rewrite certain requests to the cluster and not loop back in to the WS. I'm using the following logic in apache mod_rewrite.  It's not working:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) index.jsp?c=$1
```

Apache logs show

```
rewrite '/video' -> 'index.jsp?c=video'
```

But application (JSP Pages) aren't able to receive it.  Somehow 404 pages are being triggered before it reaches Weblogic side.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the WebLogic Proxy Plugin to do this kind of things.
Your question doesn't tell me how the Apache server know about your WLS servers ... 
have a look at the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e16435/apache.htm